# Android - Text scraps when use setScaleX()/setScaleY() in multi resolution device

Tags: android

I have a problem to use `setScaleX()`/`setScaleY()`to support muti resolution device.
I had developed one application at 1280x800 resolution device. But I want to automatically change app's layer at other resolution device. So, I have use  `setScaleX()`/`setScaleY()` at other resolution device and i have get a satisfactory result.

But there is one problem. Text also decrease or increase to fit the resolution but some scraps of text around texts.

How can I solve this problem?
Please, anyone help me with this problem. Thanks.

p.s. I had try to post the some sample image, but i can't because i'm newer.

Comment: see this link to upload image...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106053/how-do-i-display-image-in-a-post-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I know how to upload image. But I can't because I'm blocked to upload image because I'm newer.